# Get substring between substring and first occurrence of another string

Tags: javascript

I have URL pathnames that look similar to this: `/service-area/i-need-this/but-not-this/`. The `/service-area/` part never changes, and the rest of the path is dynamic.

I need to get the part of the URL saying `i-need-this`.

Here was my attempt:
`location.pathname.match(new RegExp('/service-area/' + "(.*)" + '/'));`.

The goal was to get everything between `/service-area/` and `/` but it's actually going up to the last occurrence of `/`, not the first occurrance. So the output from this is actually `i-need-this/but-not-this`.

I'm not so good with regex, is there a way it can be tweaked to get the desired result?

Comment: Your code is helpful to point out what the isuse is with your solution.  Can you please post an edit to include it?

Comment: @PaulBeverage I did explain the issue with my solution. My solution gets everything up to the LAST occurrence of `/`, I need it to go up to the FIRST occurrence of `/`.

Comment: Regex is overkill for your case. Just split URL by `/` and get 2nd part.

Comment: Sorry -- my brain apparently lost it at some point...not sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a lazy regex rather than a greedy one - so `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)`. See also: [What do 'lazy' and 'greedy' mean in the context of regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a regex too using `replace` and `split`:

```js
var path = '/service-area/i-need-this/but-not-this/';

var res = path.replace('/service-area/', '').split('/')[0];
console.log(res);
```